# Extract time from datatime in R

Tags: r

I have "datetimes" like this:

```
02FEB2015:00:06:00.000000
```

and need to extract the time as:

```
06:00
```

Tried:

```
strftime('02FEB2015:00:06:00.000000', format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Also:

```
strptime('02FEB2015:00:06:00.000000', format="%H:%M:%S")
```

which leads to NA.

But getting the error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting character to `POSIXlt` class, you need to specify exactly the same format as how the character is formulated. You can use normal `strptime` and `format` functions, an example:

As commented by @Zheyuan but slightly different:

```
format(strptime('02FEB2015:00:06:00.000000', "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"), "%M:%S")
# [1] "06:00"
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yep, seems so. `%S` captures the micro second part. Didn't know this.